# How can I make font of first slide as 8pt and other slides as10pt in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontspec, fontsize, font-encodings

I am trying to make presentation in beamer. I want my first slide in 8pt font and other slides in 10 pt fonts. But I can't make change in other slides as all slides becomes of 8 pt.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size to 8pt within the frame without affecting the other frames.

Assuming that your first frame is a title slide, you'd then also have to change the title font size as this is one is not derived from the size of the surrounding text:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{11}{14}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Used the same command given above but all slides becomes in 10 font including first slide too.

Comment: @Ashokkhanal Please make a minimal working example that allows us to reproduce your problem. With the default theme, I do get size 8 text on the first frame (with the exception of the title, which is larger than the normal text)